# iOS 7 SDK - MediaPlayer Framework - Rolling back transaction

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, mpmediaitem, mpmediaquery

The following block of code results in the error message:

2013-09-13 15:27:08.449 Mobile[746:5603] {MediaLibrary} Rolling back transaction.

```
MPMediaQuery *mediaQuery = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];
NSArray *collections = [mediaQuery collections];
```

This is in the console as of iOS 7 GM.

This worked without issue in iOS 6.

Does anyone have any idea what this relates to in iOS 7?  I have searched all over, and can find nothing about it.

In addition the message is logged on every iteration of this for loop:

```
for (MPMediaItemCollection *collection in collections) {

    for (MPMediaItem *item in collection.items) {
        //message is written to log here as well

    }
}
```

Comment: Specifically it is running on an iPad gen 3.

Comment: I filed a radar with Apple.  I will let you know when I hear back

Answer (score 3):

I'm seeing the same issue, though it doesn't seem to cause any problems.  I think this is some internal logging that they mistakenly left turned on.

Comment: If this is the case, maybe there is a way to suppress the logging temporarily.  When you want to index a 1000 songs, the log gets huge.

Answer (score 2):

In some cases when the MPMediaQuery is loaded the first time you can have

> 2013-09-19 00:28:10.636 musiXmatch[4498:1303] **{MediaLibrary}
>   Database validation succeeded** 2013-09-19 00:28:11.240
>   musiXmatch[4498:7a0b] **{MediaLibrary} Rolling back transaction.**

Other strange logs on iOS7 GM are the following

> 2013-09-19 00:28:13.643 musiXmatch[4498:7b0f] **CLTilesManagerClient:
>   initialize, sSharedTilesManagerClient** 2013-09-19 00:28:13.647
>   musiXmatch[4498:7b0f] **CLTilesManagerClient: init** 2013-09-19
>   00:28:13.649 musiXmatch[4498:7b0f] **CLTilesManagerClient:
>   reconnecting, 0x19504c90** 2013-09-19 00:28:13.651
>   musiXmatch[4498:7d03] **CLTilesManagerClient:
>   XPC_ERROR_CONNECTION_INVALID!**

Specifically the last messagge XPC_ERROR_CONNECTION_INVALID is a value of the xpc event type when doing something like

```
xpc_connection_set_event_handler(serviceConnection, ^(xpc_object_t event) {
    xpc_type_t type = xpc_get_type(event);
```

**[EDIT]**

New interesting CLTilesManagerClient logs.

> 2013-12-04 15:37:25.695 musiXmatch[274:1303] CLTilesManagerClient:
>   initialize, sSharedTilesManagerClient 2013-12-04 15:37:25.697
>   musiXmatch[274:1303] CLTilesManagerClient: init 2013-12-04
>   15:37:25.698 musiXmatch[274:1303] CLTilesManagerClient: reconnecting,
>   0x1d942d50 2013-12-04 15:37:25.700 musiXmatch[274:7b03]
>   CLTilesManagerClient: XPC_ERROR_CONNECTION_INVALID!

Comment: the problem persists in iOS 7.1 update: {MediaLibrary} Database validation succeeded

Comment: When the app is being closed a new messagge appears in iOS 7.1: {MediaLibrary} Media library service connection invalidated.